# Relating an array of objects to an enumerator

Tags: c#

How would you relate the indexes of an array to an enumerator without leaving the chance of mismatch? Example

```
public enum difficulties {
   easy,
   medium, 
   hard
}

public List<Lobby> easyLobbies = new List<Lobby>();
public List<Lobby> mediumLobbies = new List<Lobby>();
public List<Lobby> hardLobbies = new List<Lobby>();

public List<Lobby>[] lobbiesArray;

public ClassConstructor(){
    // Index order should match enumerator
    lobbiesArray = new List<Lobby>[] { easyLobbies, mediumLobbies, hardLobbies};
}


List<Lobby> lobbies = lobbiesArray[difficulties.hard];
```

Because this enumerator and array are seemingly unlinked, it is not obvious that the lobbiesArray should follow any order. What is a better way to approach this?

Comment: C# isn't my best language, but...why not `Dictionary<difficulties, List<Lobby>>`?

Comment: Dictionaries.. always forget about those

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using a wrong data structure.

In your case, you may use a dictionary where keys are the values from the enum, and the values are the actual lists:

```
var lobbies = new Dictionary<Difficulty, List<Lobby>>
{
    { Difficulty.Easy, easyLobbies },
    { Difficulty.Medium, mediumLobbies },
    { Difficulty.Hard, hardLobbies },
};

var currentLobbies = lobbies[Difficulty.Hard];
```

A few notes:

1. An array is mostly always a wrong data structure in C#. Don't use it, unless you are perfectly certain that you *need* the specific characteristics of an array.
2. Unless your team has a well-established style convention (and the inconsistencies in your code makes me think that there are none), stick with the standards. This means that `enum Difficulties`, with a capital `D`. The members of an enum start with a capital too. You can use [StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/) to check for other violations (like the lack of a new line before the opening curly bracket.)
3. Since your enum doesn't contain flags, its name should be `Difficulty`, not `Difficulties`. When you use plural, it means that you can use multiple values at once. [More on flags here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8447/240613).
4. `lobbiesArray` is a wrong name. You shouldn't have types in the names of the variables. Visual Studio makes it very easy to determine the type of a given variable, so you don't need Hungarian notation or similar constructs.
5. `ClassConstructor` is a misleading name for a method, because it makes the reader think that it's an actual constructor, while it's not (unless you actually called your class `ClassConstructor`, which is a strange name for a class.)

Comment: Thanks. On the notes, it's not production code, I just quickly wrote it for the example.

Answer (score 3):

> Relating an array of objects to an enumerator

Do you mean *relating an array of objects to an enum?*

If so then how about this ...

> it is not obvious that the lobbiesArray should follow any order.

Make it obvious by implementing; `Lobby : IComparable`, using the `enum`. The declared order in the `enum` is relevant

```
public int CompareTo(object other) {
    if(other == null) return 1;
    if(!other is Lobby) return 1;
    if((int)this.Difficulty > (int)other.Difficulty)) return 1;
    if ((int)this.Difficulty < (int)other.Difficulty)) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Then the following will sort/group by `enum` order:

```
myLobbies.Sort();
```

If `List<Lobby>` must be sub-sorted then modify `CompareTo` to include all the needed properties.

---

To make it further obvious about the `enum` I would drop the array and implement a `LobbyCollection`.

```
public class LobbyCollection {
    protected List<Lobby> Lobbies;

    // pretend we have constructor and Add method(s) as needed

    // might want to return a LobbyCollection instead.
    public List<Lobby> GetLobbies(Difficulty ofThisDifficulity) {
        return this.Lobbies.FindAll(aLobby => aLobby.Difficulty == ofThisDifficulty);
    }
}
```

---

So the `enum` declarations, `interface` implementation, and `LobbyCollection` exposing only defined Lobby behavior together make it obvious how to use a `Lobby`.  And clients don't have to make up stuff - with different client code likely doing things just ever so slightly differently.